# Why does RollingInterval.Day keep creating new Serilog Logs files?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, serilog

I am using Serilog as a logger for my program. Trying to make Rolling interval files that append the yyyymmdd date to each file.

The code below is exactly what I have used the entire time and it worked for a good 4-5 days of testing and developing my UWP app further. Then I think my app started creating multiple files with the same date titling them logs-yyyymmdd_01, logs-yyyymmdd_02, etc.

This is in the MainPageViewModel Constructor

```
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.File(this.GetFile("logs-"), rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
            .CreateLogger();
```

```
        public string GetFile(String FileName)
        {
            string s = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
            return s + "\\" + FileName;
        }
```

I have the suspicion that it is calling the constructor multiple times and that might be part of the issue. But the rolling interval should only create a new file when its a new day right? Because when the app is launched multiple times, it used to use whatever file corresponded to todays date. So I either need a way to make the Log.Logger static so that it is universal, or a way to make it use only the one file. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: pretty sure it should append as you hope - maybe it's hitting a size limit? The code in the serilog.sinks.file repo is pretty clean - recommend figuring it out from there (the tests also specify the various behaviours well)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:**

Since the rolling file is becoming deprecated you can achieve with the `Serilog.Sinks.File` package in Nuget.  The syntax for rolling file is:

```
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .WriteTo.File($@"{logPath}\log-.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
            .CreateLogger();
```

---

Have you installed the `Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile` from NuGet?  My understanding that the rolling file aspect for `Serilog.Sinks.File` is still dependent on that dependency.

With that being said I use the following:

```
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .WriteTo.RollingFile($@"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)}\Organization\{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)}\Logs\log.txt")
            .CreateLogger();
```

That defaults to a daily log file unless the size becomes too large.

Comment: Yeah I had Serilog.Sinks.File already before, it looks like RollingFile adds the syntax you just presented. I tried it out and I am still getting the multiple files created. Could this still happen if my constructor is run multiple times? Is there a better place in my code to put my Logger constructor to make sure it only runs once?

Comment: As BWhelan says @Greg, File's rolling support is ... rolled in and does not rely on `.RollingFile`

Comment: @RubenBartelink ah I see, I read it as Serilog.Sinks.File requiring RollingFile. My bad

Comment: @BWhelan Well, it should not be in a constructor.  You should have that code in your entry point or an abstracted provider that constructs it once.

Comment: @Greg Thank you, I used the call Hierarchy to figure out where my constructor for my MainViewModel was being called multiple times and that fixed the issue. Thank you for your new way of doing the RollingFile syntax!

Comment: Just  a heads-up, `RollingFile` is the deprecated, older sink; the `File` sink is the newer one.

Comment: Yeah I just saw that.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue.  Adding the **shared** parameter in the WriteTo.File() call fixed it for me:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.File(@"C:\Logs\Log_.txt", shared: true, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
            .CreateLogger();
```