# Archiving every 24 hours log files in serilog

Tags: .net, serilog

Is there any way to archive all log files of a day in a zip file in serilog? every log file is created every hour . I searched a lot and i found hooks ,but it does not have settings for my aim.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.File.Archive#readme-body-tab

in this below settings , archive started every hour

```
        "WriteTo": [
                        {
                            "Name": "File",
                            "Args": {
                                "path": "D:\\Log\\myApp\\logInformation.txt",
                                "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} [{Level:u3}] ({SourceContext}) {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                                "rollingInterval": "Hour",
                                "retainedFileCountLimit": 24,
                                "hooks": "Common.LoggingConfiguration::Archive,Common"


                            }
                        }
                    ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does RollingInterval.Day keep creating new Serilog Logs files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56569362/why-does-rollinginterval-day-keep-creating-new-serilog-logs-files)